# Convert the struct array into double array

Tags: matlab

I have combined 7 patients' data, each containing 19 features, into one struct as seen below. The data is now in a 7x1 struct with 19 fields.

[image]

What do I need to do to convert the struct to a double array? I need to use it as input for an SVM classifier. Or any suggestions for how to save the patients' data directly into a double array not a struct.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZJPK.png)

Comment: when i using in SVM 
clc;
clear all;
close all; 
load trainset.mat d
ata =new_var; 
group = label; 
SVMStruct = svmtrain(data,group,'kernel_function','linear'); 
species = svmclassify(SVMStruct,meas,'showplot',false);
the error will be "Error using svmtrain (line 241) TRAINING must be a numeric matrix".

Answer (score 1):

use `struct2array`:

```
% generating struct
dataStruct = struct;
[dataStruct(1:5).a] = deal(rand,rand,rand,rand,rand);
[dataStruct(1:5).b] = deal(rand,rand,rand,rand,rand);
[dataStruct(1:5).c] = deal(rand,rand,rand,rand,rand);
% convert it to matrix
data = reshape(struct2array(dataStruct),[],numel(dataStruct))';
```

Comment: can i know which one input,which one output? because error state that "Error using deal (line 37)
The number of outputs should match the number of inputs." I change 5 into 7 and copy''[dataStruct(1:5).c] = deal(rand,rand,rand,rand,rand);'' for 19 times because the data in 7x1 struct with 19 field ..if correct why i get error?

Comment: already solved..thank you

Comment: you don't need the first part, it's just for me to generate an example struct (as you already have). use just the last line.

Comment: sorry..but why value after change into double always changing each time i try with the same image?

Comment: because the lines constructing the structure in my code generate **random** data in the struct

Comment: sorry but i don't understand what it is..but if you can help me..what should i do if i want the the data obtained each time of the converting with the same value for same picture. because I want save this data in database for my support vector machine then as input..thank in advance

Comment: ignore my answer, just do `data = reshape(struct2array(dataStruct),[],numel(dataStruct))';` where `dataStruct` is your struct name.

Comment: sorry to disturb you again ,, but the struct convert into 19x1 complex uint8